# Error starting glassfish server - Not enough space Exception

Tags: java, glassfish

I got an exception in sun glassfish server.

I am using v2.1.1 on solaris

It is basically giving not enough space exception, but I want to know on which
directory (in solaris) it is trying to compile the jsp ?

If it is `/swap` or `/tmp` , then i checked both are having sufficient space.

```
[#|2011-05-21T12:33:56.331+0300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntJavaCompiler|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=h
ttpSSLWorkerThread-4300-12;_RequestID=9f767651-021c-480a-9a51-64a21b7b44ac;|Javac exception
Error running /home/sun1adm/jdk/jdk1.5.0_21/bin/javac compiler
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:
473)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:47)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:931)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntJavaCompiler.compile(AntJavaCompiler.java:265)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:368)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at com.tcs.common.compression.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at com.tcs.actions.login.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:672)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:603)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:877)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:383)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not enough space
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:451)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:
470)
        ... 47 more
```

---

```
--- Nested Exception ---
java.io.IOException: Not enough space
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:53)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:451)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:834)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:
470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:47)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:931)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntJavaCompiler.compile(AntJavaCompiler.java:265)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:368)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at com.tcs.common.compression.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at com.tcs.actions.login.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:672)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:603)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:877)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.portunif.PortUnificationPipeline$PUTask.doTask(PortUnificationPipeline.java:383)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
|#]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suspect this is not a matter of free disk space but free memory for the process to run the JVM to run javac.  You fork it, right?

Use "vmstat" to investigate the memory situation in Solaris while you run your program.

Comment: Thanks for reply

my issue is resolved.
I had increased heap size to 6GB, that is why i got above exception,
Now I reduced it to 4GB its working now

Thanks 
Ali

Comment: @Ali, on stackoverflow thanking is done with upvotes and answer acceptance.